# C++ SDK intergration into C# program

Tags: c#, c++, wpf, dll, wrapper

I am have been developing C# applications for a some time now, however recently I have been given a project requiring computer vision. As such my company has opted to purchase a licence for an API/SDK for a particular computer vision package. This API/SDK is however provided in:

> C++, ActiveX
>   and Direct Show based API/SDK for integration.

My question is weather C++ libraries come in the form of .dll files or some other form?

If so what options exist to integrate the c++ API/SDK into a C# WPF program in order easily build an interface and utilise its functions? and would this be considered bad practice to mix different languages?

Would it be easier to simply develop the whole program in c++?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two types of libraries in C++: dll and lib.
Dll files are dynamically linked (aka only required during runtime) whereas lib files will be linked to be part of your programm.

The library probably comes as one or multiple dll files with supporting lib files for easier access of the methods (otherwise you would have to manually look for the methods in the library when using c++).

For using them from C# you have two options: building C++/CLI wrapper or import the methods using the DllImport attribute.

The wrapper method can not really be recommended. I would only use it if there is a two way communication going on between c# and c++ (and by two way I mean more than just passing basic parameters to c++ an returning basic values).

The DllImport attribute is probably what you're looking for. Information on that can be found in the MSDN ( https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984739%28v=vs.71%29.aspx ).

Whether you want to write c++ yourself is up to you. If you want to create a UI and not do too much perfomance critical stuff in your own code I would just stick to C# where you feel at home ;-)

Comment: What about .so and .a? Don't they get any love? Nobody cares about, sob! Mono!

Comment: so if i use DLLImport Attributes can i leave the performance critical stuff to the C++ libraries and use C# to build the interface?

Comment: Yes the heavy lifting will then be done in the C++ library (native code). Concerning @user4581301: those libraries are used for linux. I am guessing you are using windows.